# cpack never finishes, at 100% CPU (infinite loop in path algorithm)

Tags: infinite-loop, deb, cpack

I am running cpack for the first time on a smallish project, containing 2 components -- 3 compiled executables, producing debian package. The packaging does not finish (maximum time I left it running was 30 minutes), it stays at 100% CPU though does not increase in RAM usage.

Attaching to cpack with gdb showed it was always in `cmSystemCools::CollapseCombinedPath` and some string manipulations. I ran again with `valgrind --tool=callgrind` and debugging symbols installed, this is sorted by inclusive time:

[image: kcachegrind output]

I am suspencting some loop in the code, as the CollapseCombinedPath got called 2.8M times and SplitPath 5.7M times (!!) within a about 30s of (instrumented) execution.

I am ATM not able to isolate MWE, but I was seeing this behavior with both cmake 2.13 and 2.10 (2.10 is where the image above is from).

When stepping through the code with breakpoint in `cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath`, I see this:

```
(gdb) break cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath
Breakpoint 1 at 0x55a6f02460a0: file ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx, line 1371.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath (dir="/..", file="..") at ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:1371
1371    in ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath (dir="/", file="..") at ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:1371
1371    in ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath (dir="/..", file="..") at ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:1371
1371    in ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath (dir="/", file="..") at ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:1371
1371    in ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath (dir="/..", file="..") at ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx:1371
1371    in ./Source/cmSystemTools.cxx
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

From the stack trace, the code is called from `cmCPackDebGenerator.cxx`, where I see

```
  for (std::string currentPath : PackageFiles) {
    while (currentPath != WorkDir) {
      // the last one IS WorkDir, but we do not want this one:
      // XXX/application/usr/bin/myprogram with GEN_WDIR=XXX/application
      // should not add XXX/application
      orderedFiles.insert(currentPath);
      currentPath = cmSystemTools::CollapseCombinedPath(currentPath, "..");
    }
  }
```

so the code is stuck there. It might be that my input is wrong (I will have to check) but cpack should definitely not hang under such circumstances.

Someone might help with this? I will try to dig more later.

Answer (score 0):

This was an upstream cmake bug, reported as [#20011: CPack/Deb: Infinite loop in path algorithm in cpack / debian](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20011) and fixed by [commit 63c0bc92](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/commit/63c0bc929240b0dd7253cced980fea0b735eb5c3).