# CPack Hangs When Packaging a Library

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, c++98, cpack

I am cross-compiling (Ubuntu 16.04, QNX, and ROS) a collision detection library and trying to package it for installation. I am compiling c++98 code using cmake 3.15.2. When I build the code (for all fore-mention OS), it builds just fine. However, when I try to package the library, it hangs when CPack is creating the package. I did a VERBOSE output of the `make package` command and got the following:

```
user@user:~/srcdir/build$ VERBOSE=1 make package
/usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -S/home/user/srcdir -B/home/user/srcdir/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/srcdir/build/CMakeFiles /home/user/srcdir/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make -f src/Common/CMakeFiles/cdl_common.dir/build.make src/Common/CMakeFiles/cdl_common.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
cd /home/user/srcdir/build && /usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/srcdir /home/user/srcdir/src/Common /home/user/srcdir/build /home/user/srcdir/build/src/Common /home/user/srcdir/build/src/Common/CMakeFiles/cdl_common.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make -f src/Common/CMakeFiles/cdl_common.dir/build.make src/Common/CMakeFiles/cdl_common.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'src/Common/CMakeFiles/cdl_common.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
[ 23%] Built target cdl_common
make -f src/CDL/Geometry/CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/build.make src/CDL/Geometry/CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
cd /home/user/srcdir/build && /usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/srcdir /home/user/srcdir/src/CDL/Geometry /home/user/srcdir/build /home/user/srcdir/build/src/CDL/Geometry /home/user/srcdir/build/src/CDL/Geometry/CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make -f src/CDL/Geometry/CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/build.make src/CDL/Geometry/CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'src/CDL/Geometry/CMakeFiles/geometry.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
[ 53%] Built target geometry
make -f src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy/CMakeFiles/bvh.dir/build.make src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy/CMakeFiles/bvh.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
cd /home/user/srcdir/build && /usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/srcdir /home/user/srcdir/src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy /home/user/srcdir/build /home/user/srcdir/build/src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy /home/user/srcdir/build/src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy/CMakeFiles/bvh.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make -f src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy/CMakeFiles/bvh.dir/build.make src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy/CMakeFiles/bvh.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'src/CDL/BoundingVolumeHierarchy/CMakeFiles/bvh.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
[ 69%] Built target bvh
make -f src/CDL/CMakeFiles/cdl.dir/build.make src/CDL/CMakeFiles/cdl.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
cd /home/user/srcdir/build && /usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/srcdir /home/user/srcdir/src/CDL /home/user/srcdir/build /home/user/srcdir/build/src/CDL /home/user/srcdir/build/src/CDL/CMakeFiles/cdl.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make -f src/CDL/CMakeFiles/cdl.dir/build.make src/CDL/CMakeFiles/cdl.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'src/CDL/CMakeFiles/cdl.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
[100%] Built target cdl
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
/usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/srcdir/build/CMakeFiles 0
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'preinstall'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/srcdir/build'
Run CPack packaging tool...
/usr/local/tsi/bin/cpack --config ./CPackConfig.cmake
CPack: Create package using DEB
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: ThinkCollisionDetection
CPack: - Install project: ThinkCollisionDetection
CPack: -   Install component: runtime
CPack: Create package
-- CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS not set, the package will have no dependencies.
```

I am still relatively new to packaging and cpack but I seem to be stuck. I have made sure to put a `PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${Relevant_Src_Includes}>` and `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/ThinkCollisionDetection>` for all of my target_include_directories(). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I used the command `cpack --debug --verbose` and got the following output:

```
CPack: Enable Verbose
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx:203 Enable Debug
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx:207 Read CPack config file: 
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx:279 Read CPack configuration file: /home/user/srcdir/build/CPackConfig.cmake
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx:342 Specified generator: DEB
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_GENERATOR, DEB)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX, /usr)
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx:412 Use generator: cmCPackDebGenerator
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx:414 For project: ThinkCollisionDetection
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:957 Create package using DEB
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:56 Create temp directory.
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PREFIX, /home/user/srcdir/build)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY, /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY, /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-.deb)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, /home/user/srcdir/build/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-.deb)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_TEMPORARY_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME, /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-.deb)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_INSTALL_DIRECTORY, /usr/local/)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_NATIVE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY, /usr/local/)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_TEMPORARY_INSTALL_DIRECTORY, /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:123 Look for: CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:127 Look for: /usr/local/tsi/share/cmake-3.15/Templates/CPack.GenericDescription.txt
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:145 Read description file: /usr/local/tsi/share/cmake-3.15/Templates/CPack.GenericDescription.txt
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION, DESCRIPTION
===========

This is an installer created using CPack (https://cmake.org). No additional installation instructions provided.

)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_PACKAGE_CHECKSUM
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_REMOVE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY, 1)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL_IN_ONE_PACKAGE
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENTS_IGNORE_GROUPS
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENTS_ONE_PACKAGE_PER_GROUP
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENTS_GROUPING
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1354 [DEB] requested component grouping = ONE_PER_GROUP
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:977 Remove toplevel directory: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:987 About to install project 
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:176 Install projects
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_INSTALL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_INSTALL_COMMANDS
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_INSTALL_SCRIPT
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_IGNORE_FILES
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_INSTALLED_DIRECTORIES
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_ALL_INSTALL_TYPES
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_DISPLAY_NAME
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_HIDDEN
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_REQUIRED
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_DISABLED
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_DOWNLOADED
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_DOWNLOAD_ALL
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_ARCHIVE_FILE
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_PLIST
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_GROUP
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_DESCRIPTION
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_INSTALL_TYPES
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_DEPENDS
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_BUILD_CONFIG
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:644 - Install command: /usr/local/tsi/bin/cmake --build . --target "preinstall"
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:647 - Run preinstall target for: ThinkCollisionDetection
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:615 - Install project: ThinkCollisionDetection
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:685 -   Install component: runtime
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_RUNTIME_GROUP
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_COMPONENT_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_INSTALL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:755 - Using DESTDIR + CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX... (mf.AddDefinition)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:758 - Setting CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to '/usr/local/tsi'
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:781 - Creating directory: '/home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi'
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_WARN_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Install configuration: "Release"
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionTargets.cmake
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionTargets-release.cmake
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionConfigVersion.cmake
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionConfig.cmake
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/include/TSCollisionDetection/CDL.h
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/include/TSCollisionDetection/cdlCommonDefs.h
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/libcdl.a
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/libgeometry.a
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/libbvh.a
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:51 Installing: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime/usr/local/tsi/lib/libcdl_common.a
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/include> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/include/TSCollisionDetection> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/include/TSCollisionDetection/CDL.h> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/include/TSCollisionDetection/cdlCommonDefs.h> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionConfig.cmake> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionConfigVersion.cmake> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionTargets-release.cmake> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/cmake/ThinkCollisionDetection/ThinkCollisionDetectionTargets.cmake> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/libbvh.a> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/libcdl.a> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/libcdl_common.a> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:885 Adding file <usr/local/tsi/lib/libgeometry.a> to component <runtime>
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_ABSOLUTE_DESTINATION_FILES, )
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:992 Done install project 
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:998 Find files
CPack: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1011 Create package
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1015 Package files to: /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-.deb
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL
CPack Verbose: /tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackDebGenerator.cxx:561 Component <runtime> does not belong to any group, package it separately.
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY, /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8--runtime.deb)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_TEMPORARY_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME, /home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages/DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8--runtime.deb)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT, runtime)
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:950 cmCPackDebGenerator::SetOption(CPACK_DEB_PACKAGE_COMPONENT_PART_PATH, /runtime)
-- CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS not set, the package will have no dependencies.
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx:1172 Warning, GetOption return NULL for: CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_GENERATE_SHLIBS
/tmp/tmpq_rpvi9v/src/Source/CPack/cmCPackDebGenerator.cxx:187 WDIR: "/home/user/srcdir/build/_CPack_Packages//DEB/ThinkCollisionDetection-1.0.0-1-g268fdd8-/runtime", length = 94
```

This is a copy of the package.cmake file which I am using:

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER ${ProjectMaintainer}) #required
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY ${ProjectDescription})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR ${ORGANIZATION})

execute_process(COMMAND git describe --tags --always --match release/*
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_TAG)
string(REGEX REPLACE "\n$" "" GIT_TAG "${GIT_TAG}")
if (GIT_TAG MATCHES "^release/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.*")
    #extract version components from tag name.
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^release/([0-9]+)\\..*" "\\1" VERSION_MAJOR "${GIT_TAG}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^release/[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+).*" "\\1" VERSION_MINOR "${GIT_TAG}")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^release/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.([0-9]+).*" "\\1" VERSION_PATCH "${GIT_TAG}")
    set(VERSION_STRING "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}")
    if (GIT_TAG MATCHES "^release/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+-.*")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "^release/[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+-(.*)" "\\1" VERSION_SHA1 "${GIT_TAG}")
        set(VERSION_STRING "${VERSION_STRING}-${VERSION_SHA1}")
    endif()
else()
    set(VERSION_MAJOR 0 CACHE INTERNAL "Version Major")
    set(VERSION_MINOR 0 CACHE INTERNAL "Version Minor")
    set(VERSION_PATCH 0 CACHE INTERNAL "Version Patch")
    set(VERSION_STRING "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}")
endif()
message(STATUS "version string: ${VERSION_STRING}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION ${VERSION_STRING})

# The following variable may be overridden by Toolchain-*.cmake
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}")
message(STATUS "CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME: ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_FILE_NAME DEB-DEFAULT)
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL runtime)

string(COMPARE EQUAL "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" QNX _cmp)
if (_cmp)
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-qnx)
else()
  set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME})
endif()

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" CACHE PATH "..." FORCE)
message(STATUS "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")

# install everything by default into the "runtime" package
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_COMPONENT_NAME runtime)
set(CPACK_STRIP_FILES TRUE)

# Hard-code installation prefix.
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR TRUE)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)

include(CPack)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
        VERSION ${VERSION_STRING}
        COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

configure_package_config_file(
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake.in"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
        INSTALL_DESTINATION lib/cmake/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(EXPORT ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Targets DESTINATION lib/cmake/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}ConfigVersion.cmake"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
```

I am setting the ${ProjectMaintainer}, ${ProjectDescription}, and ${ORGANIZATION} in the top-level cmakelists file. The CPackConfig.cmake file shows that those variables are being set correctly. Also, I am setting the version string by creating a git tag which also shows up correctly in the CPackConfig.cmake file. I am including the package.cmake file in my top-level cmakelists file and the cmake-messages in the terminal output indicate that it is being included properly.

Comment: Please, add your code into the question post (in form of [mcve]). Otherwise we simply cannot help you: without viewing your code we cannot find where it is wrong. Meanwile, there several questions on Stack Overflow about hanging in CPack. See e.g. [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019971/cpack-never-finishes-at-100-cpu-infinite-loop-in-path-algorithm) and look into the [bugreport](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20011) it refers to.

Comment: It may be caused by disk errors. You may have a try with `pstack -p $CPACK_PID` to verify it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Unfortunately I am not able to post the source code since it is proprietary. However, would providing the CPackConfig.cmake file be helpful since this seems to be a CPack issue?

Comment: We don't need your full code. We need some **small example** which is able to reproduce the same problem as you have with your actual code. Please, read what [mcve] is. Note, that the code is needed even it is CPack issue: without abling to reproduce the problem, they unlikely will be able to fix it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I added some new debugging output as well as a copy of the package.cmake which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I was accidentally setting the CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME to “” in my top-level CMakeLists.txt file. The CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME sets the CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME which was also being set to “”.